# Exchange online: How to accept emails redirected from a provider that is on Spamhaus?

Tags: exchange, office365

I am using Exchange Online Plan 1.  Additionally emails from a free email provider (gmx.net) are redirected to my exchange account.  But now, some of the SMTP servers of the free email provider are listed on Spamhaus and the Exchage server denies these emails with the following SMTP status

> SMTP error from remote server after RCPT command:
>   host: xxxxxxx-tld.mail.eo.outlook.com
>   5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [x.x.x.x] blocked using Spamhaus; To request removal from this list see http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup.lasso

(it is this Spamhaus issue:  http://www.spamhaus.org/sbl/query/SBL229649)

Is it possible to instruct Exchange online to always accept emails redirected from a certain address.  I do not have a list of IP adresses used by the blocked providers' SMTP servers.  I still want them to be filtered for Junk mail, but I do not want to deny or bounce them.

I came across a checkbox on the connections security menu to allow trusted senders, but I cannot find any field to edit this list.

edit: As a short term solution, I have disabled the forwarding and instructed exchange online to automatically fetch the mail via IMAP.

Comment: You will need to get the domains/SMTP servers unblocked via Spamhaus.

Comment: @SamuelNicholson My question is about relaxing the Exchange Online incoming blocklist for a certain source.  I do not control the blacklisted SMTP servers and they will not be unblocked in the future, according to some reports.  In case you are not familiar with GMX or its market share in certain countries, imagine all redirects from hotmail.com where handled by certain SMTP servers and that those servers were blacklisted.

Comment: The only way to relax restrictions via O365 yourself is; as far as I know via the usual mail flow options to manage accepted domains etc.. You will probably need to speak directly with Microsoft to raise a request to unblock SMTP servers. One of the drawbacks of O365 is that server access at this level is unfortunately with MS.